# ERROR: column "blob" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

```
val parquetDF = session.read.parquet("s3a://test/ovd").selectExpr("id", "topic", "update_id", "blob")
```

Trying to read parquet file and dump into Postgres. One of the column in postgres table is of JSONB datatype and in parquet it is in String format.

```
parquetDF.write.format("jdbc")
      .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
      .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_metamorphosis?binaryTransfer=true&stringtype=unspecified")
      .option("dbtable", "entitlements.general")
      .option("user", "mdev")
      .option("password", "")
      .option("stringtype", "unspecified")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .save()
```

And it fails with this erorr :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "blob" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 85
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
    ... 16 more
```

Someone on SO suggested to put `stringtype=unspecified` as then Postgres will decided the datatype for string, but it seems to be not working.

```
<scala.major.version>2.12</scala.major.version>
<scala.version>${scala.major.version}.8</scala.version>
<spark.version>2.4.0</spark.version>
<postgres.version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</postgres.version>
```

Comment: Did you manage to make it work after all? I'm facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: @BrunoGasparotto Ended up by inserting rows in DB in batches.